# Combining two 32-bit integers into one 64-bit integer

Tags: c++, integer, bitwise

```
long long combine(unsigned int high, unsigned int low) {
    return ((unsigned long long) high) << 32 || low;
}
```

1. Is there a better name for the operation?
2. Is the implicit cast from `unsigned long long` to `long long` a `reinterpret_cast`, or what happens if the `unsigned` number is too large for the `signed` data type?

Comment: Also, note that you should be using a bitwise or operator `|` rather than a logical or operator `||`.

Comment: Irk! Obviously. Thanks you for spotting it. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should return `unsigned long long` and let the user decide what they want to do with the cast, especially if you want this to be generic.

I'd prefer a name such as `u32tou64`, `uinttoull`, or something more descriptive than combine.  A lot of this will depend on your own naming standards, though.

Also, I'd consider being more pedantic:

```
return (((uint64_t) high) << 32) | ((uint64_t) low);
```

It's unlikely to make a difference because the code is essentially the same as yours, but it's easier to read and avoids extremely rare (but very troublesome to debug) casting issues.  It may require a custom types header if your compiler doesn't support this type notation.

Also, consider making it a macro.  There's little benefit to having it as a function - the operation itself will take far less time than the function call setup, call, and return, so the performance of a macro will be much higher.  Further, it isn't going to take up much more program space than a function call, so there's little to gain by leaving it a real function.

Comment: Also, it's quite possible that a union could be a more efficient way of doing this than a shift, although I would hope that most optimizing compilers make the distinction meaningless.

Comment: Thanks. I refrained from using unions because MS discourages them for alignment reasons (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284%28v=VS.85%29.aspx, "Remarks", 3rd paragraph). An optimizing compiler should also inline my function. But thanks for the suggestion, I'll probably make it a macro anyways.

Comment: Since this is C++, an inline function should be pretty much the same as a macro.

Comment: You should not be using UINT64, its so unportable.

Comment: @mathepic I always use a typesdef.h file or similar anyway.  What typenames do you suggest are more portable for those that don't?

Comment: @Adam Use `uint64_t` from `stdint.h` (a standard C99 header).

Comment: This answer didn't say it explicitly, but it implies that `unsigned int` should be `uint32_t`.